# Docker MinIO on Azure app service Map Local Drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, minio

I need to map the MinIO save path to the host, with the following syntax (docker-compose.yam) on my linux machine it works while on the Azure app service it doesn't  (all other settings in the next example work only volume settings not) why?

```
version: '3.7'

services:
 app-minio:
  image: mysite.azurecr.io/minio:latest
  command: server /data
  ports:
   - "80:9000"
  volumes:
   - data1:/data

volumes:
  data1:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/minio-data
      o: bind
```

Comment: I solved, on Azure you need to set up a gateway

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can control the mount path when you use the local volumes in Azure Web App. You only can set the volumes like this:

```
  ...
  volumes:
  - data1:/data
  ...
volumes:
  data1:
```

And when you use the local volumes, it doesn't persist the data for you.

Comment: I solved, on Azure you need to set up a gateway

Comment: @Angelo What do you mean by gateway?

Comment: I mean by using Azure blob storage

Comment: @Angelo Isn't the same as the Azure File Share?

Comment: @Angelo So set the driver is useless as I said. If so, why not accept my answer?

Comment: what you say is correct but you haven't given me a solution to use file persistence on azure app service

Comment: @Angelo Please read your question carefully, do you ask for the solution? You're asking for the reason that it does not work! I just give the thing you ask for in the question.